# TIMESTAMP as SQLite data type

Tags: .net, sqlite

I'm just starting out on SQLite in a .NET application.  And from the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), I see that data types available are NULL, INTEGER, REAL, TEXT and BLOB.  However, in examples I'm finding columns with the type TIMESTAMP for storing timestamps in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS".  I'm testing with the 'DB Browser for SQLite' application, and both TEXT and TIMESTAMP data types works fine for storing timestamps in the format mentioned above.  So my questions are:

1. What is the TIMESTAMP data type?  Is it some kind of TEXT overlay data type?
2. Are there any performance hits or considerations using either TIMESTAMP or TEXT?  I'm thinking about data type width, processing, automatic filtering of entries (e.g."banana" not allowed as an entry in a TIMESTAMP column)?
3. Why isn't TIMESTAMP documented on sqlite.org?  Are there other "Here's what's documented, but this is also possible" cases, and where can I find info about them?

Comment: You can use the data type `NAMEOFTHEGEEZER` without SQLite caring. If you look at the same page you linked to and read topic 3, type affinity, it should all make sense.

Comment: Timestamp will be mapped to text (I think).  There are no date types in SQLite.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Interesting.. "In order to maximize compatibility (...) SQLite supports the consept of 'type affinity'".  So based on that, would you recommend storing a timestamp string as TEXT or TIMESTAMP?  AFAIK SQLite won't care either way, but given that I don't know if the data will be imported into a different database type later..?

Comment: @Oystein Compatibilty is the only issue AFAIK.  Text is the only way to store a timestamp in SQLite, other than using integers to store a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: SQLITE 3 has datatype ```TIME```

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad no, it hasn't. It does, instead, offer a built-in [`time()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function (which is able to get a time/date in any format and convert it to whatever data type is appropriate).